# Expected time to get on bus

Tags: probability, poisson-process

> Suppose buses arrive at the bus stop according Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. You get on bus if it is not full. The probability that a bus is not full is $p$ and is independent of arrival time. What is the expected time to get on bus?

The question is motivated by the [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661307/whats-the-expected-time-to-get-on-bus-given-bus-coming-time-is-exp-lambda#comment9847354_4661307). I don't know what is asked in the question and its author disappeared, so I decided to ask my question. I know that $k$-th bus arrival time is a random variable with Erlang distribution, but I don't know does it lead to compact solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with a splitting Poisson process?

Comment: @MatthewH. Yes, I was. I studied probability theory many years ago and want to refresh my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected time of $n$-th arrival in Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ is $$ E[T_n] = \frac{n}{\lambda}$$. Not full buses arrive according Poisson process with rate $\lambda p$. The question asks for expected time of the first arrival of not full bus, it is
$$E=\frac{1}{\lambda p}$$